# Binding CommandParameter to UI Element outside CommandBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have AppBarButton with command binded to viewmodel (`WinRT` - windows 8.1) inside CommandBar :

```
<CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
   <AppBarButton Name="someOtherButton" ../>
   <AppBarButton Name="CropImageButton" Icon="Crop" Label="Crop image" 
                 Command="{Binding CropImageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=croppableImage, Path=OrginalSelectedArea}" />
</CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work - parameter is always null. However this binding works:

```
CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=someOtherButton, ..}
```

I fixed that by creating `SelectedArea` property in viewmodel instead of using `CommandParameter` but I'm curious are bindings to `ElementName` somehow restricted by scope?

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem. Binding a UI element to command parameter always gets null. It might be the element is not ready while executing binding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Binding with CommandBar doesn't work properly if you don't explicitly set the CommandBar.DataContext instead of using ElementName as source for the binding.

EDIT: this was a bug on WinRT 8.1 Platform. The DataContext wouldn't propagate correctly to all Page children, now this is fixed and works.

Comment: I get this same error situation in VS2015.2 for Windows10 development. I don't know if the error was fixed for 8.1, it is there for Win10!

Comment: I'm using this right now in my app and I'm pretty sure it works on 10.
No code behind, no ElementName, just plain binding. Maybe there are still some issue with the "timing" though, who knows? (e.g. *when* and *where* you set the DataContext? In my case, I set it when I navigate the page, in the OnNavigatedTo method, and all work as expected).

Comment: Thanks @Tommaso, Perhaps it's time to share some snippets? I bind the DataContext to the view using Prism MVVM's "AutowireViewModel=True" method. And there is definitely some binding going on: in my ViewModel I receive the Button as argument, but the CommandParameter remains empty.  No problem binding other buttons and setting and receiving CommandParameters from there. Anyway, I created a workaround with one line of codebehind on the AppBarButton Click eventhandler: DataContext.CommandDoMyThing.Execute(ElementName).

Comment: That's nice! other people coming in here too. My approach is like user2366741. I would b eprepared to share more code, if userful and desired.

Comment: @user2366741 Whoops, I was talking about a different thing. First there was a bug where the CommandBar's DataContext wouldn't get set unless done explicitly. The CommandParameter seems to be another issue. That can always be solved using some code behind magic (give a name to the AppBarButton of your interest and when clicked assign the interested property). I don't know if ElementName binding would work.